# Exterior entry door handle & deadbolt: What is a combined locking handle + deadbolt called?

Tags: lock, deadbolt

I need to replace the setup below.

I have searched high and low, but cannot find the integrated setup for the interior (where the door handle and deadbolt are combined, so by just turning the door handle it also unlocks the deadbolt).

What is the name for this setup?

(This one is a schlage, I am fine with anything that can be keyed as a schlage.)

[image: interior combined]
[image: exterior - handle has broken off]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

OK, it looks to be a [commercial Schlage product](https://commercial.schlage.com/en/products/mechanical-locks/s200-series-interconnected-locks.html)

The full name: "Commercial Tubular Interconnected Double Locking Entrance Lever Set"

Here they are for sale
https://www.build.com/collection/schlage/s200-series?r=24&s=SCORE&p=1

https://www.directdoorhardware.com/schlage_s200_series.htm

Pricey things.